# Memcached will not start

Tags: unix, memcached

I have this in my /usr/local/:

libevent-1.4.so.2  memcached

When I do this, it will not start:
 ./memcached -d -u root -m 3900 -p 11211
./memcached: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-1.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm sure there is a distribution-native package of memcached for your release available: You need to inform the dynamic linker of the location of shared libraries.

To do so drop your libevent into one of the paths configured in /etc/ld.so.conf (Prefer /usr/local/lib!) while making sure that you don't overwrite an existing version. If you did that, run `ldconfig`, and verify your library is known to the runtime linker by running `ldconfig -p | grep libevent`. After that, drop your memcached into /usr/local/bin/ and try running it again.

If that fails, do a `ldd /usr/local/bin/memcached` and update your question with the results.

Answer (score 1):

As it says, you have to have the shared libevent library on the machine, and where the program can find it.

[These instructions](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/how_install_memcache_debian_etch) also details how to get & compile the event library, and then have it installed properly where it can be found. Depending on the platform, it may also be installable via the usual package manager.